# ImagePicker removing views when dismissed iOS 8

Tags: ios, image, ios8

My app is structured with a central view controller that adds 3 to 4 subviews to the main view.  In one of the added view controllers I present a camera to the user.  When I dismiss the image picker, every subview except the one in which I present the camera (the view controller) disappears. I think it might be related to how the app is structured and the view stack. The app works fine when running iOS 8 on an iPhone and iOS 7 on an iPad.  I am having this issue only when I am running iOS 8 on the iPad. I made sure the code followed the apple documentation on how to present and dismiss the image picker.  Here is the code used to present the image picker.

```
 -(IBAction)photoButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    // Prompt for camera or photo library
    // Retrieve image and set it as this button's default image
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePicker.delegate = self;

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen; //play around with this

       [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera not found" message:@"There is no camera available on this device." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Code used to dismiss

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        CGSize scaleSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0f, 1280.0f);
        UIImage *capturedImage;

        // Handle a still image capture
        capturedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                     UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        if (capturedImage) {
            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([capturedImage resizedImage:scaleSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh], 5);
                photoEntity = nil;

                [self.takePhotoButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:photoData ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


                if ([self isAnyButtonSelected] || ![_answerTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || !_questionBoolean.hidden) {
                    [Tools enableControl:_saveButton];
                }


            } else {
                newPhotoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([capturedImage resizedImage:scaleSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh], 5);
                photoEntity = nil;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here I tried messing with the parent views and controllers in this method.  I was able to get the app to return to the central view controller minus the current view controller that is in charge of taking the photos.  The only problem is that the app's touch is now disabled and I am missing one view.

```
- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
{
//   [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
//    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
//   [picker removeFromParentViewController];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I was going to post photos but I am currently unable to because I am new to stack overflow.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Ok so the app is not using story boards but it is using xib files.  It is inherited code and the app was created several years ago.  There are multiple view controllers with multiple views.  There is a central view controller where all the other view controllers are added to the central view.

```
[self.view addSubview:_catViewController.tableView];
[self.view addSubview:_listViewController.tableView];
[self.view addSubview:_queryViewController.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_queryViewController.view];
```

queryViewController is where I am taking the photo.  When I dismiss every view is gone except the query view controller which happens to take up the entire screen (it previously did not).  Let me know if I need to add more information!  Thanks

Comment: Hmm... looks right to me! I wouldn't mess with the "removeFromSuperview" etc. stuff -- going that route always seems to make things worse!  Can you describe your structure some more? You have multiple view controllers with multiple views? Do you have segues between them? Storyboards? Autolayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the general problem is that your central view controller is adding the views of other view controllers to itself. You can't do that -- it breaks view controller encapsulation. And when you violate encapsulation, stuff just breaks. (That's a vague statement, but 100% true :-p)  Unfortunately, you either need to stab in the dark to find a hack to make it work, or repartition the problem to respect encapsulation. The latter is probably better if you'll need to maintain this code in the future.